# Flask app, hosting many Dash apps, each with multi-pages plugin is causing name conflicts

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I am trying to create a larger scale dashboard hosting app. This will contain many dash apps, each with multiple pages. I am getting an error when trying to put pages in separate Dash apps with the same name:

`Exception: modules ['dashboards.dash1.pages.home', 'dashboards.dash2.pages.home'] have duplicate paths`

I need to be able to run these dash apps without having naming conflicts. I have checked the page registry which shows dash is mixing up the relative paths. I understand that just not naming the pages is a solution but we are going to have lots of dashboards and that is not a suitable solution.

```
module  dashboards.dash1.pages.home
    supplied_path   /home
    path_template   None
    path            /home
    supplied_name   home
    name            home
    supplied_title  None
    title           home
    description 
    order           None
    supplied_order  None
    supplied_layout None
    supplied_image  None
    image           None
    image_url       None
    redirect_from   None
    relative_path   /dash1/home <---- SAME VALUES
    layout          H1('Dash 1 Home')
```

```
module  dashboards.dash2.pages.home
    supplied_path   /home
    path_template   None
    path            /home
    supplied_name   home
    name            home
    supplied_title  None
    title           home
    description 
    order           None
    supplied_order  None
    supplied_layout None
    supplied_image  None
    image           None
    image_url       None
    redirect_from   None
    relative_path   /dash1/home <---- SAME VALUES
    layout          H1('Dash 2 Home')
```

My codebase looks like this

```
.
├── app.py
└── dashboards
    ├── dash1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── pages
    │       └── home.py
    └── dash2
        ├── __init__.py
        └── pages
            └── home.py
```

*app.py*

```
from dashboards.dash1 import app as dash1
from dashboards.dash2 import app as dash2

app = Flask(__name__)

routes = {
 "/dash1": dash1.server,
 "/dash2": dash2.server
}

app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(NotFound(), routes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

*dash1/_**init*_.py

```
app = Dash("dash1", use_pages=True, pages_folder="dashboards/dash1/pages")

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(children='Dash 1', style={'textAlign':'center'}),
    page_container
])
```

*dash1/pages/home.py*

```
register_page(__name__, name="home", path="/home")

layout = html.H1("Dash 1 Home")
```

*dash2/_**init*_.py

```
app = Dash("dash2", use_pages=True, pages_folder="dashboards/dash2/pages")

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(children='Dash 2', style={'textAlign':'center'}),
    page_container
])
```

*dash2/pages/home.py*

```
register_page(__name__, name="home", path="/home")

layout = html.H1("Dash 2 Home")
```

I appreciate the time you took to read this long ass post!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have two dash apps, both with a page called /home. I am getting the error mentioned in the description because they are sharing namespaces for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Got confirmation that Dash does not support multiple instances running on the same process as there are many global states

https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/2812